# DateTimeInput sending empty object to graphql endpoint

Tags: react-admin

I'm using DateTimeInput for a DateTime graphql field but react-admin is sending an empty object.

So I've double checked the source prop. I've double checked the API logs and the network console on the browser.
I've also tried react-admin-date-inputs but same thing. What am I missing?

In react-admin:

```
<DateTimeInput source="datetime_start" />
<DateTimeInput source="datetime_end" />
```

When I submit the form without setting datetime_end I've got:

```
..."datetime_start":{},"datetime_end":null,...
```

On the API side I've got this error:

```
[2019-08-12 21:08:24 +0200] DEBUG in views: {"errors":[{"message":"'dict' object has no attribute 'split'"}]}
```

I don't understand why react-admin is sending an empty object for that field to the API.

Any help is very welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can it be related to https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3171 ?

Comment: I'm suspecting `ra-data-graphql-simple`
With a rest endpoint it's working fine.

Comment: I am facing the same error, did you solve it already? 

I am using `ra-data-graphql-simple` lib

Answer (score 0):

ok so turned out there is a very easy workaround, I am not sure what is happening behind the scenes but I think the adapter (`ra-data-graphql-simple`) is trying to convert Date object to json.

In docs:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#transforming-input-value-tofrom-record

You can define a data transformer that can do the value conversion for you:

```
<DateTimeInput source="end_at" validate={required()} parse={v => String(v)} />
```

And on the form submission you can see the data in network inspect displayed correctly:
[image: network inspect graphql request]

Just casting value to string is not very good idea but at least it gets the information across do not forget to always normalize the data because these inputs can return different values depending on the browser and its settings.